# Uniform Convergence; Continuity

Tags: calculus, continuity, uniform-convergence

> [image]

In the last step. I believe we did

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{a}^{x} g = \frac{d}{dx} \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{a}^{x} f_n' = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{d}{dx} \int_{a}^{x} f_n' = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n'(x)$$

How come we are allow to switch between the limit operator and the differentiation operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $g$ is continuous, $\int_a^x g(t)\,dt$ is differentiable and its derivative is $g(x)$. (Fundamental theorem of calculus.)

So the last step is just differentiating the equality
$$
f(x)-f(a) = \int_a^x g(t)\,dt$$
and using the earlier computation and the assumption that $f_n'$ converges (even uniformly) to $g$.

Comment: No, no,no. I am asking about the last, last, last line of the proof.

Comment: @sidht Maybe you're forgetting that $f_n'$ converges (even uniformly) to $g$ by assumption?

Answer (score 0):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus $$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{a}^{x} g=g(x)$$But, by the first part, also $$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{a}^{x} g=\frac d {dx}[f(x)-f(a)]=f'(x)$$This is all.

Comment: No, no, no, that's not what I am asking. I am asking about the final sentence.

Comment: I don't understand why you speak of a 1-dimensional vector: I don't see it.

Comment: Never mind about that then. I was asking about their final conclusion.

Comment: There is a misunderstanding: the possibility of switching between the limit operator and the differentiation operator is the thesis of the theorem, not a means to prove it.

Comment: Then how did they arrive at the final sentence? And am I wrong then?

Comment: Your chain of equalities is valid only if you apply the theorem you want to prove: therefore it cannot be accepted as a way to prove the same theorem.

Comment: So then how did they conclude $g(x) = \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)$

Comment: There is a mistake in your comment.

Comment: Yes, I meant $f'_n$